# when block matrix is positive definite ,

Tags: block-matrices

can one tell me when the block matrix M=[A B,C D] is positive definite such as:

1-the four block A,B,C and D are symmetric diagonal positive definite matrices

2-M is asymmetric, so C is not the transpose of B, and we can not apply schur formula

Comment: Why can't we apply the Schur complement?

Comment: because C is not the transpose of B

Comment: You are looking at a particular case of the Schur complement. A sufficient condition that $M$ be positive definite is that the Schur complement $A-BD^{-1}C$ be positive definite.

Comment: but for my knowldege, the schure complement  is applied when C is the transpose of B

Comment: You can use the Schur complement in more general situations. See here, it talks about both. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Comment: you can not, go to the site web you gave me and see that when we use the shure complement to talk about positive defintnesse, C should be the transpose of B